# Who am I flying with?

Tags: check-in, skyteam

I purchased a ticket from PIT to CWL with stops in DTW & AMS through a 3rd party website. I'm 99% certain it's KLM, but the ticket lists Endeavor Air, Delta. & KLM Cityhopper for the connections.

The return is similar, I'm thinking they are Air France flights, with the connection flights being KLM Cityhopper, Air France & Delta.

I've been able to view my booking on Air France, Delta, & KLM. I just want to make sure I check in at the right counter.

Also, since CWL is my final destination, that's where I'll go through the questioning with the immigrations officer, correct?

Comment: I and family have flown the Cardiff to America via Amsterdam route a few times, and the operator of the main flight varies.  We have had KLM, Delta, or Air France.  I'm not sure if you can tell ahead of time.  However, Berwyn's answer is correct for check in in any case.

Comment: KLM and Air France are in effect one and the same company as from may 2004. They have a joint venture on the transatlantic route with Delta and Alitalia. http://www.klm.com/corporate/en/about-klm/cooperation/joint-venture.html

Comment: After a little bit of looking around I figured it out. Of the three airlines, Delta is the only one that operates in Pittsburgh, and KLM in Cardiff.

Answer (score 9):

You always check in with the carrier operating your first segment. You'll need to give the flight numbers to be certain, but it sounds like it will be Delta. If you are transitting through AMS you should go through customs and immigration in CWL. On the return, it sounds like you will be on KLM Cityhopper and will therefore check-in at the KLM desk.

[image]
[Endeavour Air](http://www.endeavorair.com/) is a wholly owned subsidiary of Delta Air Lines

Comment: This trip seems awful...

Answer (score 2):

Booking through 3rd party websites can give you either a single airline booking or a pieced together multiple airline booking.

If all your flight numbers start with KL then you likely have a KLM marketed ticket using code-share flights.  Likewise if the flights numbers all begin with DL (Delta) or AF (Air France), it would be a fare marketed by that respective airline.

If the segments have different identifiers, one DL, two KL or such, then your flight is a collection of individual flights pieced together.

In both scenarios, you would normally check in with the operating airline of the first flight, but in your case Endeavor Air is under contract to operate Delta flights so you would check in with Delta.

Comment: I appreciate the responses so far. The flight numbers wasn't even something I thought of looking at. The first 3 flights all have "KL"  identifiers, while the returning 3 have "AF" identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The fun of "code shares": In order to make their network look bigger, airlines code-share flights with partners. For example AMS -> Cardiff is both DL936 and KL1059. It's not unusual to have up 4 or even 5 flight numbers for a single flight. One of those airlines actually owns the plane and the crew. That's the "operating carrier". You always need to check in with the operating carrier of the first leg of your flight.

Now as added complications some "operating carriers" are wholly owned subsidiaries. They operate the flights but you can't book tickets directly with them and they don't have check-in counters. In this case you need to check in with the "owner of a subsidiary operating carrier". Clear as mud ?

Here is the answer then: in PIT you check in with Delta, and in CWL you ckeck in with KLM (who owns Cityhopper) for flight KL1059